# Is it possible to enable make shorcuts or actions available when windows is locked?

Tags: windows-8.1

I would like to set up some actions that could be performed when windows is locked (win + L).

Think volume control when an ipad or android device is locked. Something like that.

I say run a shortcut because I could easily plug any function if I could do that.

It seems weird that I can control volume and a few other actions, but I cannot add or cotnrol these actions. Or can I?

My reason for this is that I have a notebook on my desk, besides my desktop. I use it for some specific actions (upload a file, backup, *stop/play music*) that I could easily hook up to shortcuts. If I leave it unlocked, I will forget to do it when I go for coffee, or some other task (mostly coffee). If I lock it, I'll have to unlock it for every task.

Comment: When you say locked do you mean logon screen or what please specify

Comment: Yes locked as by win + L. I suppose the behavior I want could be applied to login screen, but I don't think you could run programs before loging in.

Comment: only via hackery. My favorite is to replace the screen magnifier with a cmd.exe instance. then you can launch a shell from the login screens accessibility options, and best of all it runs as `NT Authority\System`. Of course I neveer run MY systems like that, but ....

Comment: @FrankThomas that is really clever i like that

Comment: Only drawback is I think you would need on accessibility item for each action you want to hook up... unless you control it by how many times you run it in a certain interval and.... {walks away mumbling}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best specific option for your query is probably Windows Kiosk mode, where you can configure the netbook to only present a limited number of features. then you could disable screen lock without comprimising your security (unless your music is security sensitive I suppose).

There are several hacks that allow sneaky actors to set up fake responses to instrumentation on the lock screen, like the shutdown options or the Accessibility options. Here is one example: http://www.askvg.com/how-to-launch-command-prompt-or-other-programs-using-ease-of-access-button-at-login-screen-in-windows-vista-and-7/ . That said, this is probably not viable for your workflow, and really is a hack.